# Overleaf Community Edition (Sharelatex) | How to read the changed LaTex file from disk?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, latex, overleaf, sharelatex

I've installed [Overleaf](https://github.com/overleaf/overleaf) on my personal server (Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS). After the installation, I figured out that Overleaf save the LaTex files (.tex, .bib, ...) and the compiled file (.pdf) in `INSTALL_PATH/data/sharelatex/data/compiles/*project_folder*`. Each time, if I make some modifications from my browser and recompile the project, the above folder will be automatically updated.

However, if I change directly the .tex file in a texteditor (not in the browser), then I reopen the project in the browser the LaTex file on the left panel is not updated. But if I check the .tex file in the above folder, it is truly changed and saved.

So how can I make this to be possible?

Here is an illustration of what I expect:
[image: Expected result]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think that the content's file comes from the mongoDB, then when you see the file on the web, the content is loaded from the database not of the file.

If you make changes on the file directly, they're rewritten from the database.
I believe that for this reason you can restore changes from the History option, because the content of the file is stored on the database.